# Difference between javascript getTime() and Java getTime()

Tags: java, javascript, date, negative-number, gettime

It seems that Java and JavaScript give different results for negative millisecond values.

JAVA:

```
System.out.println(new Date(-12220000000000L));
Wed Sep 26 12:33:20 MST 1582
```

JavaScript:

```
console.log(new Date(-12220000000000));
 Date {Wed Oct 06 1582 12:33:20 GMT-0700 (LMT)}
```

There is a 10 day difference in their outputs. But for some values, the difference is less than 10 days. I used W3C TryIt editor to test JavaScript output. I don't know exactly where the deviation begins. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why would `new Date` accept something like that ? Do you have any documentation that shows the Date constructor accepting negative numbers.

Comment: Technically the Java API docs says that negative integers are allowed. Don't know about the JavaScript api.

Comment: In what locale? I note the first is in "MST" and the second is in "LMT"

Comment: @adeneo:Negative numbers are valid arguments for Date constructor both in Java and JavaScript. In any case, there is no difference between the two as long as  absolute values of the numbers are small enough. I haven't tried to find the exact number a deviation occurs between the two.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: LMT stands for Local Mean Time. Actually, MST=GMT-07. Anyway, this can't be a timezone issue. There is 10 day difference. No two time zones are that much apart.

Comment: Here's a little conundrum to make you confused -> **http://jsfiddle.net/svu9L6ys/**

Comment: The deviation begins at -12219292800000. Java goes from Oct 4 to Oct 15, and Javascript goes from Oct 14 to Oct 15.

Comment: for -30000000000000 java gives: Tue Apr 28 1019, and JavaScript gives: Tue May 04 1019.
It seems the difference is not always fixed. For -50000000000000, the difference becomes only 1 day!

Comment: @jrook See [Conversion between Julian and Gregorian calendars #Conversion table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_Julian_and_Gregorian_calendars#Conversion_table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nashorn, you can see when they deviate:

```
> function printDate(x) { System.out.println(new Date(x) + " - " + new java.util.Date(x)); }

> printDate(-12219292800000)
Fri Oct 15 1582 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) - Fri Oct 15 00:00:00 GMT 1582

> printDate(-12219292800001)
Thu Oct 14 1582 23:59:59 GMT+0000 (GMT) - Thu Oct 04 23:59:59 GMT 1582
```

This corresponds to a switch from the [Julian to Gregorian calendar](http://www.findingdulcinea.com/news/on-this-day/September-October-08/On-this-Day--In-1582--Oct--5-Did-Not-Exist-.html).

Java's date library takes this change into account, but JavaScript's doesn't.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this? Because the difference doesn't seem to be fixed and seems to be decreasing as the absolute value of the Date argument increases.

Comment: @jrook You can try the `GregorianCalendar` class in Java instead of `Date`.

Comment: or check Jodatime or the Java 8 Date api

Comment: @jrook Use [GregorianCalendar.setGregorianChange(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setGregorianChange-java.util.Date-) and set it to a date prior to the range you are working with.

Answer (score 3):

The default date for the switch from [Julian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) to [Gregorian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) calendar in Java's [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class [*"is October 15, 1582 (Gregorian). Previous to this, dates will be in the Julian calendar."*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setGregorianChange-java.util.Date-)

Hence, the OP's Java date of Sep 26, 1582 is a Julian date. The difference between Julian and Gregorian dates in 1582 was [10 days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_Julian_and_Gregorian_calendars#Conversion_table).

If the JavaScript implementation in question doesn't respect the Julian to Gregorian switch but works with Gregorian dates regardless of the point in time we are at the situation the OP experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Both java `getTime()` and `javascript` `getTime()` returns many milliseconds have passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. Negative argument calculate the date to the past.

I found a [bug in jdk](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7109480) . Reading this it seems in jdk 7  there is a lack of 10 days from **Oct 5 1582 to Oct 15 1582**. I think the 10 days difference from `javascript` `getTime()` comes from this bug.

Comment: It's not a difference of 10 days, it's 2 days: _"JRE6 jumps from Oct 5 1582 to **Oct 17 1582**"_ vs.  _"JRE7 jumps from Oct 5 1582 to **Oct 15 1582**"_

Comment: It's a difference of 10 days when comparing JRE7 to JavaScript.

Comment: @fgb Yes, that's what the OP found out already. The JDK bug report doesn't mention JavaScript but a 2-days difference between JRE6 and JRE7.